# AWS VPC Connect Endpoint and Workbrench integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I have some RDS instances under a private subnet and a bastion host (ec2 instance) with a public IP to connect to it. As part of getting a security certification we need to get rid of all ec2 instances with a public ip. We still need though connect to RDS. I found how to connect to the bastion host through AWS SSM and VPC instance connect endpoints using AWS credentials but this will only work in the terminal. Manipulating data (RDS databases) thorugh the terminal is not fancy enough to give it a try. We used Workbrench with the "Standard (TCP/IP)/IP over SSH". Is there a way I can connect privately to RDS from Workbrench?

Connect privately to RDS from Workbrench